# Userprofile messed up

Tags: powershell

I have a little problem here with my user profile path for the use with powershell.
I have set my profile.ps1 to this:

```
$Shell = Host.UI.RawUI
$Shell.WindowTitle="PowerShell obeys me!"
$Shell.BackgroundColor="White"
$Shell.ForegroundColor="Blue"
$size = $Shell.WindowSize
$size.width=120
$size.height=50
$Shell.WindowSize = $size
$size = $Shell.BufferSize
$size.width=120
$size.height=5000
$Shell.BufferSize = $size
```

but everytime i execute run poweshell, it shows some erors like this one:

```
Property 'WindowTitle' cannot be found on this object; make sure it exists and is settable.
At D:\data\d7bighs\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\profile.ps1:5 char:8
+ $Shell. <<<< WindowTitle="PowerShell obeys me!"
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (WindowTitle:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyNotFound
```

now is i check my profile it tells me this:

```
$profile
d:\data\myusername\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1
```

but if i check this through windows explorer it tells me this:

```
d:\User\myusername\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\profile.ps1
```

Im confused here because within explorer tells me d:\Useres but PS shows it as d:\data...

How can i change this or force PS to look after d:\users instead of d:\data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a tiny error: `$Shell = $Host.UI.RawUI`, and you may need to create the profile first by

```
 New-Item -Path $PROFILE -Type file
```

then edit it by

```
 notepad  $PROFILE
```